# Water leaks through obstacle

Tags: fluid-simulation

Every time I try to hold water with a obstacle, it leaks out. Here is one example I have made.

[image: Water leaking through bowl]

The shape has no holes, and the water is partially contained but slowly leaks out. This has occurred every time I have tried this. What could the cause be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Setting the obstacle's volume initialisation to shell seems to have fixed it

[image]

I have no idea why this works if anyone knows why please add it to the comments.

Comment: The other solution would be to make the walls of your obstacle thicker. If you need to render with thinner walls, then have two meshes. Simulate with the thick-walled one and render with the thin walls.

Comment: Is it possible the normals on your obstacle were messed up?

Comment: @Fweeb the walls of the obstacle where prity thick, changing the thickness didn't have any effect.

Comment: @qwertie They don't appear to be particularly thick in your screenshot. Also, sometimes it helps to apply any Object mode scaling (Ctrl+A) on obstacles before you simulate.

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped when I applied *Surface Thickness* to the obstacle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply modifiers on your obstacle, especially Solidify. Fluid seems to leak when the obstacle's geometry has to be computed on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running water through a pipe and I changed the time scale to lower and the axis direction to a littler lower and it seems to flow perfectly no leakage but still maintaining a good amount of water flow