# Fluid leaks even through two thick obstacles

Tags: fluid-simulation

In short:  **My moving obstacle leaks all the fluid that it's supposed to hold. I have tried tens of changes in the parameters (and all the solutions to similar questions), but it's not going to get better. What haven't I tried yet?**

I've been very conservative and redundant with my obstacles: the ladle (already solidified to a completely unrealistic thickness) is duplicated and its copy gets scaled up even further during movements. The two ladle obstacles are initialised as shell and volume respectively.

However, even after trying different settings and setups, with or without the redundant obstacle, this is the average result:

[image]

My ladle spills all of the soup before reaching the target! And it does so even when the motion is really slow.

Also: the volume of fluid in the ladle is getting thinner and thinner but I'm not sure whether this is balanced by the fluid going out through the obstacle.

In conclusion: I have [both **Shell and Volume obstacles**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5580/water-leaks-through-obstacle/5581#5581), my obstacles should be already [**properly solidified**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5580/water-leaks-through-obstacle/35067#35067) and pretty thick, I have tried [with and without "***Remove air bubbles***"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50814/prevent-fluid-to-flow-through-the-walls-of-an-obstacle/50869#50869), and I've even tried using an ***Impact Factor*** of 1.05 (very funny experiment: the ladle still leaked but it eventually created new soup on its way back to the pot). [My **resolution**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80990/fluid-gets-stuck-in-the-middle-of-pipe/80992#80992) is 300 and the ***Scales* are all applied** to approximately real world scales.

In a total of 48 hours of simulations done, redone, and redone again, I haven't found a way to make it look right.

What else can I do before I scrap this project?