# What fluid obstacle movements cause the majority of fluid to disappear?

Tags: fluid-simulation

This is a narrow question, so your narrow answer is appreciated.  At this point I do not want to include a picture.

A fluid simulation was working well enough in timespan A.

In timespan B an obstacle was placed and fluid behaved as expected for many frames.  Obstacle and Fluid interacted.
Then one of the following events occurred

- Subtle movements of fluid obstacles. Including obstacles coming nearer to each other or farther from each other.  More inportant.
- Cyclical fast  and abrupt movement  of the obstacle.  Less important.

These event seemed to coincide with the disappearance of say 99% of fluid.  So any comments may need to categorize moving obstacles or stationary obstacles.  These scenario descriptions are guesses. I am seeking confirmation.

I saw no large amount of fluid on the domain walls. Then the water inflow seemed to stop as well.

I have witnessed similar behaviour before with Blender Fluid Simulation

Have others witnessed this behaviour?  It would be my preference to hear from people with similar experiences.

A related question could be ... Are there certain classes of fluid simulation in Blender that are known to fail or be beyond the scope of Blender FS?

I sometimes use obstacles to hydro form the fluid.  Thus it is not my goal to [push into] water, according to a comment below, yet I may be doing so.  I am waiting for a comment clarification.

Comment: I've had problems where an obstacle pushes into a fluid - it's as if any fluid that ends up within the obstacle is simply 'lost' to the simulation. Can you share a Blend file that shows the problem?

Comment: Please clarify [pushes into] 

Comment: I’ve had issues wherever an obstacle moves towards a fluid while in contact with that fluid - including where the fluid is contained *within* the obstacle. It’s as if the fluid can react to a stationary surface but if that surface moves to overlap the fluid the fluid is effectively destroyed.

Comment: I think this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/116872/29586 might be related - where the fluid disappears when the container moves - I believe it's as the fluid (slightly) overlaps with the container as the container moves towards the fluid that causes the issue.

Comment: The question above may be related IMHOIIHO in that Blender Fluid Simulation has undesirable behaviour.  Though I have not tried to accomplish what he attempted.

Comment: @RichSedman I am not sure I have seen,  or have the patience to see ... [fluid is contained within the obstacle].  How did the fluid get in the obstacle in the first place.  Low Resolution ... High Velocity?  In some simulations there could be 100 obstacles.

Comment: Please share a Blend file demonstrating the issue.